# when i run my script to fetch data from other 2 sheets it is arranged the shown in picture of master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

[master sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJV7a.jpg)

this is my code
the names are displayed under names  numbers to be displayed under numbers but it is displayed under names ..I have 2 sheets named as{name,number} and a  master sheet contains id,name number.
when i run the script  it ftches data but not accordingly

```
function addMenu()
{
 var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Merge');
 menu.addItem('Run Script', 'MergeSheets');
 menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen()
{
 addMenu(); 
}
//combine data from multiple sheets
function MergeSheets() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = null;
  var RetrieveSheet = null;
  var PasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var sheets = ['Name','Number'];
  PasteSheet.getRange(2,1,PasteSheet.getLastRow(),PasteSheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  
  for (var i =0; i<sheets.length; i++){
    RetrieveSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    if (RetrieveSheet.getName() != 'Master'){
      data = RetrieveSheet.getRange(2,1,RetrieveSheet.getLastRow(),RetrieveSheet.getLastColumn()); 
      data.copyTo(PasteSheet.getRange(parseInt(PasteSheet.getLastRow())+1,1));
    }
  }
}
//update data changes to each sheets
function updateBasedSheet()
 {
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master');
  var valueMaster = master.getRange(2, 1, master.getLastRow(), master.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var Name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Name');
  var Number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Number');
  var dataName = valueMaster.filter( function(item){
  return item[2] === 'Name';
 }
 
 );

  var Number = valueMaster.filter( function(item){
    return item[2] === 'Number';
  });

  Name.getRange(1, 3, dataName.length, dataName[0].length).setValues(dataName);
  Number.getRange(1, 3, dataNumber.length, dataNumber[0].length).setValues(dataNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to join 2 sheets, and they have same length and id correspondesce, you can use

```
var data1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Name').slice(1);
var data2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Number').slice(1);

var mergedData = data1.map( (index, row) => row.concat(data2[index]) );

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master')
  .getRange(2, 1, mergedData.length, mergedData[0].length)
  .setValues(mergedData);
```

Comment: thank you so much if possible can u adjust it in my code..

Comment: It is hard for me to understand what all of your code does, especially w/o seeing 2 others sheets. I believe you should put my code in MergeSheets.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72387968/thank-you-as-i-have-attached-screenshots check this